# Using SQL query with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, sql

I'm creating a tool that when you type in the city name it will select the city, zoom in and label it. I have the zoom and label working but can't figure out the SQL Query needed to select the city I type in the tool in ArcMap. My code in below.

I'm still new at this

```
import arcpy as ARCPY

def citySelect():

    mxd = ARCPY.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
    df = ARCPY.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
    city = ARCPY.GetParameter(0)
    cities = ("N:/Lab13/Lab13/cities.lyr")
    ARCPY.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("cities", "NEW_SELECTION",''' "CITY_NAME" = ' city ' ''')
    print city[0]
    layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df)
    citiesLayer = layers[0]
    df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()
    citiesLayer.showLabels =True
    ARCPY.RefreshActiveView()

citySelect()
```

Comment: You have a different potential issue too. You have a variable `cities` which is pointing to a layer file, but `SelectLayerByAttribute_management` uses a quoted string `"cities"` which implies you're have access to a layer straight from the map table of contents--which may not be available depending on the context of how you are running this.

Comment: This is an aside to your issue, but I think `import arcpy as ARCPY` makes your code awkward to read when everyone here seems to use the simpler `import arcpy`.

Answer (score 3):

The call to SelectLayerByAttribute could be handled like this:
`ARCPY.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('cities', "NEW_SELECTION", "CITY_NAME = '{}'".format(city))`

Comment: Ok thanks for the response! I'm going to try to get to the lab to try it tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) to pull in the city name and guarantee that it is a string.

You can then print it to confirm its name before using it in SelectLayerByAttribute.

Changing:

```
ARCPY.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("cities", "NEW_SELECTION",''' "CITY_NAME" = ' city ' ''')
```

to:

```
ARCPY.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("cities", "NEW_SELECTION",'"CITY_NAME" = ' + "'" + city + "'")
```

should then work.