# Select by attributes with user input using Python

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute

I am new to GIS and Python is not my forte, so I am looking for some help. Ideally, what I am trying to do is create a tool that allows the user to select an address from my Address points layer. I need to select values from multiple fields: STREET_NUMBER, STREET_NAME and STREET_TYPE. What I really need help with is building my expression. Here is what I have so far:

```
# Import system modules
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

# Set workspace
workspace = r"O:\Users\Student\Scratch\SC_Test.gdb"

# Set variables
stNum = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)    
stName = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)    
stType = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

# Make layer from feature class
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("Address", "add_lyr")


arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("add_lyr", "NEW_SELECTION", "STREET_NUMBER" =  stNum)
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS stack exchange.  There are tons of questions around here like yours, here's one that may help http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144838/using-sql-query-with-arcpy  If you're still getting errors, it's best to include them in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Your where clause needs to be wrapped in quotes.  Also, is the 'STREET_NUMBER' field numeric?  If so, your expression can be fixed by doing this:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("add_lyr", "NEW_SELECTION",'"STREET_NUMBER" = {}'.format( stNum))
```

If it is a text field, you will need to wrap that in single quotes:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("add_lyr", "NEW_SELECTION", ''' "STREET_NUMBER" = '{}' '''.format( stNum))
```

Comment: I ran the tool in ArcMap using just the STREET_NUMBER parameter (which is numeric) to test and the tool ran fine, however it did not select anything from my Address layer. Maybe I should be more explicit... I want this tool to select an address from my Address layer, that way it can be easily located in ArcMap. I also want the expression to facilitate my STREET_NAME and STREET_TYPE fields, which are both text, to locate a single, specific address. Thank you !

Comment: Perhaps instead of just having a text parameter for the stNum variable, you can just change that parameter to a SQL data type and that way you can use the Select By Attribute GUI.  You will have to make sure that it is obtained from your Address Feature class though.